# Modulus with divisor unknown

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the answer to this question, but more importantly, a general formula.

> $x$ is a positive integer which solves the following questions: when $280$ is divided by $x$, the remainder is $16$; when $900$ is divided by $x$, the remainder is $42$. Find the greatest possible value of $x$.

It's quite obvious that $43\leq x\leq264$, and I've converted the above into the equations $280=kx+16$ and $900=mx+42$. I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Is my answer right? Please check once .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $280 = kx + 16$ and $900 = mx + 42$, simple transpositions give us $858 = mx$ and $264 = kx$. Thus, $x$ is a divisor of $858$ and $264$. What is the greatest such divisor?(Think : greatest common divisor). Do you know a "general" procedure for finding the greatest common divisor?

Do you think that this satisfies the conditions of the question, and is the largest such number to do so?

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised I haven't come up with the answer myself now that I think of it.

Comment: Actually, I should point out : suppose this gcd were less than $42$, then the remainder upon division cannot  be $42$. So we are restricted to divisors of $264$ which are greater than $42$, and there are not too many to check, so in this case one need  not even go through the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

When $280$ is divided by $x$, the remainder is $16$. What does this tell you about the remainder when $280 - 16$ is divided by $x$?

Comment: Is my answer right?

Answer (score 0):

The number which you are looking for has to be the HCF of $858$ and $264$ because the two conditions have to be fulfilled simultaneously.  Thus the answer is $66$. You can use Euclid Algorithm or Prime factorization method to find HCF.

Note : HCF denotes Highest Common Factor

Comment: HCF? What is HCF?

Comment: Highest common factor @5xum or Greatest common divisor

Comment: Is the answer right?

Comment: It's *correct*, but I think we should spare the extra 1.5 seconds to write out ambiguous abreviations such as HCF...

Comment: Should I replace it with GCD?

Comment: Btw please upvote my answer if you like it,